# How to dynamically update the rotation of a cube with react-three/fiber?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-spring

I am attempting to set the rotation of a cube, on click, with react-three/fiber.  I would like to be able to click the box and have it rotate from its current angle to a new angle of rotation, each time the cube is clicked.  Currently, I have a **react-three/fiber** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tlockhart/revolving_cube), however, the animation does not stop at the right angle, and will not restart.  I am assuming this is because the clock.elapsedTime continues to run, even while the animation pauses.   Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Comment: The Codesandbox link (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tlockhart/react-spring-test) isn't working for me

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I have added a new codesandbox, as the other link was not working.